# Can't connect asp.net page to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to use a database on my asp.net website, but i have some problems with connecting to my host. I use the following code and i got an error:

```
private const string ConnStr = "Provider=MSDASQL; Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=pdb9.xxx.net;Database=xxx;User=xxx;Password=xxx;Option=3;";    
using(OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
using(OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO sample(name, address) VALUES (?,?)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
    cmd. Parameters.Add("@address", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    BindDataGrid();
}
```

The error appears when i call con.open();

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I always used the MySQL database on my PHP pages and it worked fine. Besides Mysql my host also supports PostgreSQL. Does someone know how i can solve this problem or how to find a solution using a database on an asp.net page?

Comment: are you using 64bit windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how commonly MySql connection string look like in config file:

```
<add name="name" connectionString="server=IP;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE;persist security info=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

in code:

```
vat connectionString = "server=IP;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE;persist security info=True"
```

And i suggest you to use MySql Connector For .NET, you can install it using [NuGET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.8.3) or from [official site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString **syntax** is like

```
connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Database=YourDatabase;Server=localhost;UID=YourUsername;PWD=YourPassword;"
```

Comment: This is the connection string i tried before, but i got the some error.